# Count_sort function in python3, not allowed to use built in functions, must be in O(n+k) complexity

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, counting-sort

the prompt:

Use the count sort algorithm to write a function that receives a StaticArray and returns a new StaticArray with the same content sorted in non-ascending order. The original array must not be modified.
You may assume that the input array will contain at least one element, and that all elements will be integers in the range [-109, 109]. It is guaranteed that the difference between the maximum and minimum values in the input will be less than 1,000. You do not need to write checks for these conditions.
Implement a solution that can sort at least 5,000,000 elements in a reasonable amount of
time (under a minute). Note that using a traditional sorting algorithm (even a fast sorting algorithm like merge sort or shell sort) will not pass the largest test case of 5,000,000 elements.
For full credit, the function must be implemented with O(n+k) time complexity, where n is
the number of elements and k is the range of values.

this is for an algo class so no built in functions allowed. Also not allowed to use for loops that iterate through an array, but a for loop to iterate through a range is fine.

my code:

```
   low = min_max(arr)[0]
   high = min_max(arr)[1]
   arr_size = StaticArray.length(arr)
   result = StaticArray(arr_size)
   count_array = StaticArray(high - low + 1)
   # initialize result and count_array to have 0 at all indices
   for num in range(0, count_array.length()):
       count_array[num] = 0
   for num in range(0, result.length()):
       result[num] = 0
   # count the occurence of each item 
   num = 0
   while num < arr_size:
       pos = arr[num]
       count_array[pos - low] += 1  # offset indexing
       num += 1
   # back sum
   for j in range(1, count_array.length()):
       count_array[j] += count_array[j - 1]
   # place value in result array
   num = arr_size - 1
   while num >= 0:
       result[count_array[arr[num]] - 1] = arr[num]
       count_array[arr[num]] -= 1
       num -= 1
   return result
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong. It is throwing an out of bounds error.

the static_array.py file is a static_array class that essentially disables the iteration through an array and the use of built in methods.

```
class StaticArray:
    """
    Implementation of Static Array Data Structure.
    Implemented methods: get(), set(), length()

    Any changes to this class are forbidden.

    Even if you make changes to your StaticArray file and upload to Gradescope
    along with your assignment, it will have no effect. Gradescope uses its
    own StaticArray file (a replica of this one) and any extra submission of
    a StaticArray file is ignored.
    """

    def __init__(self, size: int = 10) -> None:
        """
        Create array of given size.
        Initialize all elements with values of None.
        If requested size is not a positive number,
        raise StaticArray Exception.
        """
        if size < 1:
            raise StaticArrayException('Array size must be a positive integer')

        # The underscore denotes this as a private variable and
        # private variables should not be accessed directly.
        # Use the length() method to get the size of a StaticArray.
        self._size = size

        # Remember, this is a built-in list and is used here
        # because Python doesn't have a fixed-size array type.
        # Don't initialize variables like this in your assignments!
        self._data = [None] * size

    def __iter__(self) -> None:
        """
        Disable iterator capability for StaticArray class.
        This means loops and aggregate functions like
        those shown below won't work:

        arr = StaticArray()
        for value in arr:     # will not work
        min(arr)              # will not work
        max(arr)              # will not work
        sort(arr)             # will not work
        """
        return None

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        """Override string method to provide more readable output."""
        return f"STAT_ARR Size: {self._size} {self._data}"

    def get(self, index: int):
        """
        Return value from given index position.
        Invalid index raises StaticArrayException.
        """
        if index < 0 or index >= self.length():
            raise StaticArrayException('Index out of bounds')
        return self._data[index]

    def set(self, index: int, value) -> None:
        """
        Store value at given index in the array.
        Invalid index raises StaticArrayException.
        """
        if index < 0 or index >= self.length():
            raise StaticArrayException('Index out of bounds')
        self._data[index] = value

    def length(self) -> int:
        """Return length of the array (number of elements)."""
        return self._size
```

The exact error that is being given in the console is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/deleted for privacy/Desktop/CS261/assignment1/assignment1.py", line 414, in <module>
    result = count_sort(arr)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/deleted for privacy/Desktop/CS261/assignment1/assignment1.py", line 247, in count_sort
    result[count_array[arr[num]] - 1] = arr[num]
           ~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/deleted for privacy/Desktop/CS261/assignment1/static_array.py", line 87, in __getitem__
    return self.get(index)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/deleted for pr/Desktop/CS261/assignment1/static_array.py", line 73, in get
    raise StaticArrayException('Index out of bounds')
static_array.StaticArrayException: Index out of bounds
```

Comment: What is the implementation of `StaticArray`?.  Make a [mcve] and provide a complete stack trace of the error.

Comment: Also, is `sorted in non-ascending order` a bad way of saying descending order?  Your algorithm is trying to sort ascending which is certainly not "non-ascending"

Comment: @mark I made the edits you requested, but there is no way to make the static_array.py shorter without coomprimising the information. Also, non-ascending sort as I understand means that it is in ascending order but can have duplicates. For example, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6 is in non-ascending order.

Comment: You forgot to offset the `count_array` by `low`.  The line with the error should be `result[count_array[arr[num] - low] - 1] = arr[num]`.  Also fix the line after it.  Also I'd still consider 1,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,6 as ascending.  That's normal for an ascending sort.  You should clarify with your instructor.

Comment: @mark that was it! I had that previously but I did not edit the line below to offset by low. Thank you so much. I think it was me looking at code for too long and needing fresh eyes.